# Change URL for a given Service

Tags: angularjs, service

I am attempting to setup an application to hit multiple environments but with the same path after the environment. I have a proxy setup to look at the path and forward it to the correct service.  I am trying to accomplish this with using the services and prefixing my path with a /dev, /stage/ or prod.  Can I modify a service in the module after it has been created to switch to the appropriate environment and prepend the environment to the path?  Will I have a service created for each separate environment?  A little new to Angular so trying to figure out my best options.

Example:
    localhost:8080/dev/user/{id}
    localhost:8080/stage/user/{id}
    localhost:8080/prod/user/{id}

Comment: of course you can, you can modify anything not hardcoded during runtime... now can you show an example of your service and people (like me) can help you out. It's easier to help when people post code... doesn't have to be your actual code just a section which you are having trouble with.

Comment: Yeah there is a lot of code to post but as an example I have several factories that are consuming a URL.

Comment: 'code'
var services= angular.module('services', [ 'ngResource']);


function getHost(){
     return window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/webapp/' + 'test';
}


services.factory('Customers', [ '$resource', function($resource) {

    return  $resource(host +  '/api/customers', {}, {
     query : {
            method : 'GET'
        }
    });
} ]);
'code'

Comment: So in this example i want to change the value in getHost() dynamically.  So "test", "stage", and "prod" for all the different environments that are going to reside on the same URL. Just seems like factory has host stored in one instace. So I wasn't sure if i just need to somehome create function to set this dynamically a not.

Comment: why don't you make the return dynamic dependent on the current configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function getHost(){ 

    // qa by default
    var hostToReturn =  window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/webapp/' + 'test'; } 
    if( condition to determine if production )
        hostToReturn = different value;
    if( condition to determine if staging)
        hostToReturn = another different value;

    return hostToReturn;
}
```

Comment: Yeah,  I am trying to inject that into the $resource as well. It seems though once a $resource is created it won't accept my new URL